# Firing javascript on multiple ids

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

My coffee script gets launched through this line:

```
$(document).on 'change', '#myid1'
```

Now it should also get launched on changes of

```
'#myid2'
'#myid3'
'#myid4'
.
.
.
And so on..
```

And it should also remember the number that launched the script. For example if #myid1 gets changed the javascript should get fired and save the "1".

How do i do that?

Best regards!

Comment: `$("[id^=myid]").on('change',function(){})` should do the trick.

Comment: `$(document).on("change", "#what, #ever, #id", function() { ... });`

Comment: Is that javascript or coffeescript?

Comment: Why don't you give them a class so you can refer to them as a group?

Comment: To follow up on @Maverick's suggestion: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: If you plan to use jQuery, why not invest an hour of your own time into browsing through the [list of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - in which case you'll find how to do [multiple selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and [attribute starts with selectors](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/). Even better, browse through the [full list of methods and selectors](http://api.jquery.com/) - it really doesn't take that long to read the brief descriptions, and it'll save you lots of time in the long run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

Code :

```
$(document).on('change', '#myid1, #myid3, #myid4', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var num = id.substring(id.length - 1, id.length);

    alert(num); // Should alert the correct value (1, 3, 4 etc...)
});
```

You may also want to look at adding a class to each element (i.e. `<input type="text" class="inputElem" id="myid1" />`

And then change to code to handle changes based on this class instead of listing the Ids :

```
$(document).on('change', '.inputElem', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var num = id.substring(id.length - 1, id.length);

    alert(num); // Should alert the correct value (1, 3, 4 etc...)
});
```

Comment: An even better solution would be to add a `data-attribute` on the element like `data-num=1` and alert this attribue `alert($(this).data('num'));` in order to avoid problems with multi-digit numbers (10, 100, 1000...)

Comment: Hey thanks fpr that answer helped me a whole lot. Problem is that the substring will only give me the last digit. So if I got myid10 it will return 0. Tried to use this instead: `var num = id.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");` but it gives me back an error.